# Cannot read bit value on where clause

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I hope you could help me out today. I am getting a problem in my where clause. Sql query did not seems to read the value of my logical field.

here is the code:
I want to select the employee name which is still `active(1)`, but it always shows the inactive `emplyees(0)`. Please help me out. Thanks!

```
$sql="select distinct fname, lname, mname, position, empcode from emplist where fname like '%".$ename."%' and active ='1'";
```

Comment: If `active` is a bit field, you can remove the single quotes around 1. Also, the query looks OK - are you getting all records or only those with `active=0`?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried what you said, but nothing's change. My query both gets all the records both 0 and 1. But when I try to run a query on sql server, it seems fine. It doesn't show inactive employees.

Comment: What is the actual value of `$sql` after the `$emp` variable has been passed to it?

Comment: you mean the $ename variable? it shows the name of employees that i type in the search box

Comment: The SQL query that you construct in your PHP code depends on the value of the $ename variable so it may be different from the query you run directly on SQL server with hard coded value.

Comment: Also as a best practice, you should use parameterised queries instead of concatenating like your present code.